# Constants in Haskell algebraic datatypes

Tags: haskell, constants, algebraic-data-types

Is it legal in a Haskell algebraic datatype to have constant values in the declaration? In other words, can I define something like this:

```
data HttpStatusCodes = BadRequest "Bad request" 400
                     | NotAuthorized "Not authorized" 401
                     | -- ...
```

I tried to figure it out from the specification, but the grammar is not clear to me.

Comment: No, it's not legal. It also doesn't really make sense; what are you trying to do?

Comment: After posting the question last night, and thinking about it some more, I believe that I am trying to do exactly what @Zoidberg' answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you are not allowed to do that (data *types* are *types*, not *data*). Instead you can do the following:

```
data HTTPStatus = HTTPStatus Int String

badRequest, notAuthorized, notFound :: HTTPStatus
badRequest    = HTTPStatus 400 "Bad Request"
notAuthorized = HTTPStatus 401 "Not Authorized"
notFound      = HTTPStatus 404 "Not Found"
```

or, similar:

```
data HTTPStatus = BadRequest | NotFound

code :: HTTPStatus -> Int
code BadRequest = 400
code NotFound = 404

message :: HTTPStatus -> String
message BadRequest = "Bad Request"
message NotFound = "Not Found"
```